# How to to fetch data from the linkedin API using jquery

Tags: json, api, linkedin-api

I am trying to fetch data from the LinkedIn API but I am receiving an error when going to this link https://api.linkedin.com/v1/jafarosalami/~86qrm3ajsgj8vn?format=json I receive this error:

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Unknown authentication scheme",
  "requestId": "99T1AAITD8",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1524664549979
}
```